# `pip install pygments` incomplete install when run as build phase in XCode

Tags: python, xcode, pip, kivy

I am running the command:

```
pip -v install pygments==2.0.2 --force-reinstall --ignore-installed --target .
```

as part of my build process in a Kivy iOS project. When I run the command myself in the terminal, pygments is installed correctly. When XCode runs it, the pygments package does not install any files in the `pygments/formatters` directory.

I have verified that the same pip is used for my user and when XCode runs `pip`.

Output when I install pygments:

```
(rdoherty.local) %% pip -v install pygments==2.0.2 --force-reinstall --ignore-installed --target .                                       ~/Documents/projects/kivy-ios/racecapture-ios/YourApp (master)
Downloading/unpacking pygments==2.0.2
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pygments/2.0.2: 404 Client Error: Not Found
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pygments/2.0.2 when looking for download links for pygments==2.0.2
  [snip]
  Using version 2.0.2 (newest of versions: 2.0.2, 2.0.2)
  Downloading Pygments-2.0.2-py2-none-any.whl (672kB):
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/P/Pygments/Pygments-2.0.2-py2-none-any.whl#md5=98f29db02f4b22f58a2d3f60646e1e1f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pygments/)
...Downloading Pygments-2.0.2-py2-none-any.whl (672kB): 672kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: pygments
Successfully installed pygments
```

Output when Xcode runs the exact same command:

```
Downloading/unpacking pygments==2.0.2
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pygments/2.0.2: 404 Client Error: Not Found
  [snip]
  Using version 2.0.2 (newest of versions: 2.0.2, 2.0.2)
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/P/Pygments/Pygments-2.0.2-py2-none-any.whl#md5=98f29db02f4b22f58a2d3f60646e1e1f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pygments/)
Installing collected packages: pygments
Successfully installed pygments
```

I have downloaded the file that pip downloads and verified it contains files in the `formatters` directory. I have verified that the same `pip` program is being used for both myself and XCode:

```
(rdoherty.local) %% which pip                                                                                                            ~/Documents/projects/kivy-ios/racecapture-ios/YourApp (master)
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

How or why would pip incorrectly unzip or install pygments when run in an Xcode build phase vs directly?

Comment: How are you running the command under XCode? You have verified that it is the same pip command, but is the PYTHONPATH  the same?

Comment: I'm running pip directly as a 'Run Script' command: http://i.imgur.com/1exnXWv.png


`cd "$PROJECT_DIR"/YourApp

pip -v install pygments==2.0.2 --force-reinstall --ignore-installed --target .`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a PEBKAC issue. Kivy iOS projects have a few default build steps and one of them is to delete all *.py files in your app's directory. Normally this is fine because there is a step before this that compiles all the .py files to .pyc. But my build steps had the `pip install` command running after the compilation step. So all .py files were being removed inside the Pygments directory before they were compiled to .pyc.